# Android dev, raw resource can't be found

Tags: android, inputstream

I get except when I try to open a file in the `res/raw` folder.

```
InputStream in = Resources.getSystem().openRawResource(R.raw.eng_sample);
```

The exception is:

```
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0X89890
```

I can see the file `eng_sample.txt` in the apk in `res/raw/eng_sample.txt`.

On top of that when I do `R.raw.` and press `Ctrl-space` the file `eng_sample` is given as a suggestion.

What is the problem then? How do I fix this?

Thanks kindly in advance.

P.S.

I also tried putting the file `eng_sample.txt` into the `main/assets`. And then fetching the file with

```
InputStream in = context.getAssets().open("file:///android_asset/eng_sample.txt
```

but now I get an IO exception.

Maybe someone can tell me how to make this approach work instead of the one above?

Answer (score 1):

`Resources.getSystem()` returns a shared global Resources object that provides access to only system resources (no application resources).

Also `context.getAssets().open(fileName/*not path*/)` is used to get file from the assets directory, you should supply just the fileName, not the whole path.

To open stream from a raw file, use:

```
context.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.eng_sample);
```

Answer (score 1):

I have been using this code for same purpose. You can do some thing like this

```
BufferedReader mReader = null;
 try {
         mReader = new BufferedReader(
    new InputStreamReader(getAssets().open("eng_sample.txt")));
 String mLine;
 while ((mLine = mReader.readLine()) != null) {
       //do your stuff with line
       ...
    }
  } catch (IOException e) {
    //print stack trace
  } finally {
     if (mReader != null) {
          try {
                   mReader.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                 //print stack trace
           }
       }
   }
```

Hope it helps.